# Identity 2.0 Users are getting redirected back to Login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

Here is my login code, the problem happens to users redirected to "Profile" after logging in.

```
 protected void UserLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsValid)
            {

                var manager = new IdentityModels.UserManager();

                IdentityModels.User user = manager.Find(Username.Text, Password.Text);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    if (isUserActive(user.PatientId)=="isNotActive")
                    {
                        lblError.Text =
                            "you are no longer active. Please contact your local clinic to find out why.";
                        return;

                    }
                    if (isUserActive(user.PatientId) == "clinicNotActive")
                    {
                        lblError.Text =
                            "Your clinic is no longer active. Please contact your local clinic to find out why.";
                        return;

                    }
                    IdentityModels.IdentityHelper.SignIn(manager, user, RememberMe.Checked);

                    if (manager.IsInRole(user.Id,"Administrator") || manager.IsInRole(user.Id,"Staff") || manager.IsInRole(user.Id,"Physician"))
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("Dashboard");
                    }


                    if (Request.QueryString["Profile"] != null)
                    {
                        IdentityModels.IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["Profile"], Response);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Response.Redirect("Profile");
                    }


                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password");
                    lblError.Text = "Invalid username or password";
                }
            }
        }
```

here is my page load code on the Profile page:

```
 var manager = new IdentityModels.UserManager();
            IdentityModels.User user = manager.FindById(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());

        if (user == null)
        {

             var ex = new Exception("patient was null, BUT TRIED SIGNING IN NOW" + UserAccess.GetUserId().ToString());
                Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);

            Response.Redirect("Login");
        }
```

Elmah logs show the exception "patient was null, BUT TRIED SIGNING IN NOW 0".

So if my users are signing in successfully, which they must be because they are hitting the profile page, then why do some of them hit this error. Why is the user null?

I just can't figure it out, why it effects some but not all. When I republish the website all users can then login for a few minutes, sometimes a few hours, then it starts again.

Comment: Are you using Forms Authentication or Windows Authentication?

Comment: @Claies I'm not sure, because neither is in my web.config.

Comment: then you are probably using forms authentication.  the `HttpContext.CurrentUser.Identity` is derived from a cookie which is set in the client after successful login, containing the authentication ticket.  If the cookie isn't available or has expired, then `Identity` will be null.  Therefore, I would check to see if the users have cookies disabled.

Comment: @Claies they don't have cookies disabled, because it happens from my computer when I try to sign in their account.

Comment: hmm, well then I would start off with trying to log what you have in the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()` call, what user that value gets from the `FindById()` method, and compare it to what is in your database.

Comment: I'm on a cloud based web host, do you think `<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">` could be the cause?

Comment: because I want to add that this only happens on the live server and never in the development environment, which is why this is so weird and unexpected.

Comment: if your application is distributed across multiple servers (web garden) then InProc sessionState could certainly cause this kind of behavior.

Comment: 1 server in the cloud hosting two websites, only 1 site is using any authentication.

Comment: I still think you should log those variables and do some manual comparisons, especially if it only happens to certain users and is not specific to the machine they are using.

Comment: Is the IdentityHelper.SignIn method calling Signin as expected. The only reason I see here is that the auth cookie is not set in the response and in that case the redirect to 'Profile' page is not authenticated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK guys, here is the answer.

Change the session state from InProc, in my case to SQLServer, it's been 22 hours since a login redirect, which hasn't happened before, so I think it's safe to say the problem is solved and that was the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `User.Identity` rather than `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity`. I've seen some cases where the context (which is based on ASP.NET's session) gets out of sync with Identity's tokens.